# deciding order of elements in parent container

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

newbie here. I have two shortcodes that I want to display on one single page. Essentially, I want to display a users profile page(built in shortcode with one of my wordpress plug ins) and then display extra information(from another shortcode which I have wrote specifically). The problem is the second shortcode is always displaying above the first, and I need it the other way around. they both belong to the same parent container, and in the edit page I have them in the correct order, but for some reason it will never display in the correct order. Cant post images cause of the reputation rule, but the html looks like this.

```
 <div id="content">
     <div class="my_box3">
     <h2>
        <div class="uultra-prof-cont" style="background-color:#e8e8e8 !important">
        <input id="receiver_id" type="hidden" value="40">
     </h2>
     <p> </p>
     <hr>
     <hr>
     <p> </p>
     <p style="text-align: left;"></p>
     <h2></h2>
 </div>
```

I need the class "my_box3" to show up after the h2 elements. I cant edit the php file that writes the h2 element cause its from my plugin and I have tried many different things. Is there anything I can do to assign to the "my_box3" element to ensure it comes last?

```
content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffd1b2;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 5px 5px;
    width: 69%;
}


.my_box3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.uultra-prof-cont {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: do you have only these two elements inside "content" or more?

Comment: I edited the code snippet, There are no other elements inside "content", although I left out the elements inside the profile container and "my_box3"

Comment: is there any CSS for the div id's and classes that we're not seeing here? I would imagine some CSS needs to be cleared if your having stacking issues.

Comment: I have added the css for those 3 elements.